# Horner algorithm

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, algorithm

I have a question about my console program.
It has to count using Horner algorithm. There is no exception thrown, however, it does not give the right results.

If anyone could help me I would be very grateful, because I do not know what to do ...

Here is the code of my program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Consola_Horner_Rekurencyjnie
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n;

            Console.WriteLine("Podaj stopień wielomioanu: ");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int[] a = new int[++n];

            Console.WriteLine("Podaj wartosc a: ");

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("a [" + i + "] = ");
                a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            int x;

            Console.WriteLine("Podaj x:");
            x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int Horner;
            Horner = a[0];

            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                Horner = Horner * (i - 1) * x + a[i];
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Wynik to:" + Horner);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the second option calculates the code, but the counts are all wrong:

```
Func<int, int> Horner = null;
Horner = (i) => (i == 0) ? a[0] : Horner(i - 1) * x + a[i];

Console.WriteLine("Wynik to:" + Horner(x));
Console.ReadLine();
```

I wanted to rewrite the original code from C + + (in the form of a recursive algorithm).

The original code looks like:

```
int Horner;
int n;
int *a = new int[n];
int x;


int main()
{

        cout <<"Podaj stopień wielomianu: ";
        cin >> n;
        cin.ignore();


        cout << "Podaj wartość a: \n";
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
           cout <<"a[" <<i<<"] = ";
           cin >> a[i];
           cin.ignore();
        }

        cout <<"Podaj x: ";
        cin >> x;
        cin.ignore();

        cout <<"Wynik to: " << Horner(n);

        getchar ();
        return 0;
}

int Horner (int i)
{
        if (i == 0)
           return a[0];
        else 
           return Horner (i - 1) * x + a[i];
}
```

Already I do not know how to do it ... Wandering still in the same place ...

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking

Comment: What are you truly trying to do in code.. is this an application that takes user input..? if your counts are off also look at your for loop C# is 0 based in regards to indexing so if you are setting things up to start your count at 1 you need your < statement to be variable - 1 you are mixing and matching counts..

Answer (score 2):

You're unnecesarily multiplying by `(i-1)` in your loop.

Change it to:

```
        int Horner;
        Horner = a[0];


        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            Horner = Horner  * x + a[i];
        }
```

or even better to:

```
        int Horner = 0;

        foreach (int wspolczynnik in a)
        {
            Horner = Horner  * x + wspolczynnik;
        }
```

You probably saw some implementation that had `Horner(i-1) * x + a(i)`, but the `(i-1)` is an array index in this case, not a multiplier.

**edit:**

On the other hand your recursive version takes one parameter - the degree of the polynomial, and you tried to call it with x. Do it with n!

```
int result = Horner(n);
```

IMO it would be much clearer if it took 2 parameters - degree of the polynomial, and x:

```
Func<int, int, int> Horner = null;
Horner = (i, x) => (i == 0) ? a[0] : Horner(i - 1, x) * x + a[i];

int result = Horner(n, x);
```

Comment: Must be the version of the code, (Horner (i - 1) * x + a [i],) because it is a way of counting using a recursive method.

Previously specified manner (Horner = Horner * x + a [i]) is a method of interaction.

Comment: @mcshow yeah, so you simply mixed them up :) the first (iterative) code you posted has that spurious (i - 1).

Comment: Pasted above the original code from C + + and tried to convert it to C # I have no idea what else I can do ... My program gives poor results.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. But there is still a problem because now the program shows me something like that declared the "x" can not be used at this point because there is already another piping spot and has a different meaning.

And I have already declared an "x" so that the user can give him.

Comment: i guess that's a name conflict. Does it happen in the two-parameter version? if yes change x in Horner definition to y. I'm not really sure how scoping works in case of lambdas in c#.

Comment: As I change the "x" in the definition of Horner to "y" but this does not work. Error does not show, but the program does not compile to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I found here "good" source code in c# for [Horner scheme](https://www.projectik.eu/index.php/programovanie/csharp/item/280-c-hornerova-schema):

```
private IEnumerable<int> getDivisors(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return (IEnumerable<int>)new int[] { 0 };
    else
        return Enumerable.Range(-Math.Abs(n), 2 * Math.Abs(n) + 1)
            .Where(a => a != 0)
            .Where(a => (n % a) == 0);
}
private bool findRootWithHornerScheme(int[] coefficientsA, int x, out int[] coefficientsB)
{
    var lenght = coefficientsA.Length;
    var tmpB = new int[lenght];
    coefficientsB = new int[lenght - 1];
    tmpB[0] = coefficientsA[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < lenght; i++)
    {
        tmpB[i] = tmpB[i - 1] * x + coefficientsA[i];
    }
    //ak je posledny koefiecient B == 0 ,tak zadane x je korenom polynomu
    if (tmpB[lenght - 1] == 0)
    {
        Array.Copy(tmpB, coefficientsB, lenght - 1);
        return true;//bol najdeny koren
    }
    //nebol najdeny koren a metoda vrati false
    return false;
}
```